# Play! Framework - Como carregar os arquivos públicos (js, css, img) uma única vez?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, play-framework

Olá,

Comecei a utilizar o Play! Framework a pouco tempo com AngularJS, e estou tendo problemas pra utilizar services do AngularJS, pois seto uma variável em uma página e quando vou consultar essa variável em outra página o valor é null. Percebi que a aplicação carrega os arquivos estaticamente toda vez que eu acesso uma página.

Como eu faço pra carregar esses arquivos uma única vez na aplicação, pra depois não ter que baixá-los de novo (a cada página acessada) e perder os valores das minhas variáveis js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular é um *framework* para SPAs (Single Page Applications). É fácil preservar dados entre mudanças de escopo - entretanto se você está recarregando a sua aplicação é necessário que você armazene-os entre cargas.

Preserve seus dados em `localStorage`, e recupere-os a cada vez que sua aplicação for inicializada.

Seguem algumas *libraries* que você pode utilizar para este fim:

- https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
- https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Encontrei nessas _libraries_ a solução para o meu problema.